# ReactJS onClick state change one step behind

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I'm building a very primitive quiz app with ReactJS and I'm having trouble updating the state of my `Questions` component. Its behavior is it renders the correct index of the `questions` array to the DOM  despite `this.state.questionNumber` always being one step behind in `handleContinue()`:

```
import React from "react"

export default class Questions extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      questionNumber: 1
    }
  }

  //when Continue button is clicked
  handleContinue() {
    if (this.state.questionNumber > 3) {
      this.props.unMount()
    } else {
      this.setState({
        questionNumber: this.state.questionNumber + 1
      })
      this.props.changeHeader("Question " + this.state.questionNumber)
    }
  }

  render() {
    const questions = ["blargh?", "blah blah blah?", "how many dogs?"]
    return (
      <div class="container-fluid text-center">
        <h1>{questions[this.state.questionNumber - 1]}</h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.handleContinue.bind(this)}>Continue</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I am unsure I understand your question. I do see that you are accessing the `this.state.questionNumber` right after you have queued an update for it. 
Setting a state in React is an async operation so there is no guarantee it will update in time for the next function call.


From the official doc: _setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value._

Comment: What would be a good alternative in this case?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`setState()` is [not necessarily a synchronous operation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> `setState()` does not immediately mutate `this.state` but creates a pending state transition. Accessing `this.state` aft
>
> There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to `setState` and calls may be batched for performance gains.

For this reason, `this.state.questionNumber` may still hold the previous value here:

```
this.props.changeHeader("Question " + this.state.questionNumber)
```

---

Instead, **use the [callback function](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate) that is called once the state transition is complete**:

```
this.setState({
    questionNumber: this.state.questionNumber + 1
}, () => {
    this.props.changeHeader("Question " + this.state.questionNumber)
})
```

Comment: I really like this callback function solution

Comment: The callback function is a godsend

Answer (score 1):

As Sandwichz says, if you access the state right after using setState, you have no guarantee of the actual value. You could do something like this:

```
handleContinue() {
  if (this.state.questionNumber > 3) {
    this.props.unMount()
  } else {
    const newQuestionNumber = this.state.questionNumber + 1
    this.setState({
      questionNumber: newQuestionNumber
    })
    this.props.changeHeader("Question " + newQuestionNumber)
  }
}
```