# I want to fetch the current value of text input field by using onChange event in react

Tags: reactjs, input, onchange, react-state

The problem with the onChange event is, it is providing the value but with one character less.

Example : if  I type "overflow" in the input box, the provided value will be "overflo" (without w).
It's not registering the last character input.

How can i get the full text from the input field. Is there any other way to solve this problem.

```js
import React, {useState} from "react";

function Average() {

    const [totalVal, setTotalVal] = useState("");
    const [shares, setShares] = useState("");

    const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
      if (event.key === 'Enter') {
        setTotalVal(totalVal + "+");
      }
    };

    const calcAvg = (event) => {
    
      let avg = eval(totalVal) / shares;
      
      document.getElementById("avgBox").innerHTML = ": ₹" + avg.toFixed(2);
      
      event.preventDefault();
    };
    
  return (
    <>
      <div>

          <div className="my-4">
            <label className="block">
              <input
                type="number"
                id="totalShares"
                className="mt-1 px-3 py-2 bg-white border shadow-sm border-slate-300 placeholder-slate-500 focus:outline-none focus:border-slate-300 focus:ring-slate-300 block w-full rounded-md sm:text-sm focus:ring-1"
                placeholder="Enter number of stocks"
                value={shares}
                onChange={(event) => setShares(event.target.value)}
              />
            </label>
          </div>
    
          <div className="my-4">
            <label className="block">
              <input
                type="text"
                id="stockVal"
                value={totalVal}
                className="mt-1 px-3 py-2 bg-white border shadow-sm border-slate-300 placeholder-slate-400 focus:outline-none focus:border-slate-300 focus:ring-slate-300 block w-full rounded-md sm:text-sm focus:ring-1"
                placeholder="Enter price of every stock with + in between"
                autoComplete="off"
                onChange={(event) => {setTotalVal(event.target.value); calcAvg()}}
                onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
              />
            </label>
          </div>

          <div
            className="p-2 my-8 unselectable cursor-pointer flex w-full justify-center bg-green-400 hover:bg-green-500 text-white font-medium rounded"
            onClick={calcAvg}>
            Average Price<div id="avgBox"></div>
          </div>

      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Average;
```

Comment: can you share the code

Comment: can you share your code please

Comment: it's input max length attribute may cause problem or in your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you `setTotalVal` and immediately call `calcAvg`. Since setState is *[sort of async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41043419/reactjs-onclick-state-change-one-step-behind)* this function won't have the updated value until the next render.

You can fix this by using another state in combination with a `useEffect`. We'll create `averageValue` state to store the average value. Then we add the `useEffect` to run whenever the `totalVal` or the `shares` change. Instead of the `document.getElementBy` we can simply display the average value [the React way](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/thinking-in-react).

I removed the `calcAvg` since we don't need it anymore when using the new functionality.

Note: It is not recommended to manipulate the DOM using `document.getElementBy...`.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function Average() {
  const [totalVal, setTotalVal] = useState("");
  const [shares, setShares] = useState("");
  const [averageValue, setAverageValue] = useState(0);

  const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      setTotalVal(totalVal + "+");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const avg = eval(totalVal) / shares;
    setAverageValue(avg);
  }, [totalVal, shares]);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <div className="my-4">
          <label className="block">
            <input
              type="number"
              id="totalShares"
              className="mt-1 px-3 py-2 bg-white border shadow-sm border-slate-300 placeholder-slate-500 focus:outline-none focus:border-slate-300 focus:ring-slate-300 block w-full rounded-md sm:text-sm focus:ring-1"
              placeholder="Enter number of stocks"
              value={shares}
              onChange={(event) => setShares(event.target.value)}
            />
          </label>
        </div>

        <div className="my-4">
          <label className="block">
            <input
              type="text"
              id="stockVal"
              value={totalVal}
              className="mt-1 px-3 py-2 bg-white border shadow-sm border-slate-300 placeholder-slate-400 focus:outline-none focus:border-slate-300 focus:ring-slate-300 block w-full rounded-md sm:text-sm focus:ring-1"
              placeholder="Enter price of every stock with + in between"
              autoComplete="off"
              onChange={(event) => {
                setTotalVal(event.target.value);
              }}
              onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
            />
          </label>
        </div>

        <div className="p-2 my-8 unselectable cursor-pointer flex w-full justify-center bg-green-400 hover:bg-green-500 text-white font-medium rounded">
          Average Price: ₹ {averageValue.toString()}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Side note: Although [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) works, I suggest you try and take a look into storing your stock prices and amounts within some kind of array. This way you can, in the future, for example list all of you stocks.

Comment: Yes, It would be a good idea to store the value of all stocks in array. Thanks Sir

Comment: RubenSmn can you please suggest a way to show a prompt message that the entered value is not correct. I don't want to use alert because it is not got for ux.

Comment: @PushkarDangi you can create some basic `error` state where you set a error message is the input is incorrect. When the input is correct you can set it back to a empty string or null. If there is a error message your render your message, else not.

Comment: I got it, but how should i show the message on display.

Comment: You can use [conditional rendering](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/conditional-rendering) to determine if you should display the message or not. And you could build some custom alert or modal component to display the message.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of getting input values with `useRef()` hook.

```
const ref = useRef();
  const handleChange = () => {
    console.log(ref.current.value);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>I'm trying to get input value</h2>

      <input
        type="text"
        ref={ref}
        onChange={handleChange}
        placeholder="type something..."
      />
    </div>
  );
```

CodeSandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-framework-ge6w2e?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks MN A, it is highly motivating to know that there are people who wants to help beginners also. And you are one of them :)

Comment: @PushkarDangi You're welcome. try to use `useRef()` hook for getting input value because of its performance.

Comment: Does it have any other advantages over useState

Comment: I mentioned the best practices to get input values . `useSate` has different advantages. And also `useRef` is not over the `useSate`, it's entirely up to you to use the best practices of the `hooks`.

Comment: You could google it or you could read the official docs of reactjs.